# How to consistently set EditText Selected Underline Color Programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android, textinputlayout

I'm trying to build a renderer for Xamarin Forms. The renderer needs to set the `EditText` underline color to "Active Color" when selected and "Hint Color" when deselected. My initial setup looks something like this.

note: here's the path to the full source file
https://github.com/XamFormsExtended/Xfx.Controls/blob/issue-%236/src/Xfx.Controls.Droid/Renderers/XfxEntryRendererDroid.cs

```
// called when control is created or when Colors are changed.
protected virtual void SetLabelAndUnderlineColor()
{
    var defaultColor = GetPlaceholderColor();
    var activeColor = GetActivePlaceholderColor();

    SetHintLabelDefaultColor(defaultColor);
    SetHintLabelActiveColor(activeColor);
    SetUnderlineColor(_hasFocus ? activeColor : defaultColor);
}

private void SetUnderlineColor(AColor color)
{
    var bg = ColorStateList.ValueOf(color);
    ViewCompat.SetBackgroundTintList(EditText,bg);
}

private void SetHintLabelActiveColor(AColor color)
{
    var hintText = Control.Class.GetDeclaredField("mFocusedTextColor");
    hintText.Accessible = true;
    hintText.Set(Control, new ColorStateList(new int[][] { new[] { 0 } }, new int[] { color }));
}

private void SetHintLabelDefaultColor(AColor color)
{
    var hint = Control.Class.GetDeclaredField("mDefaultTextColor");
    hint.Accessible = true;
    hint.Set(Control, new ColorStateList(new int[][] { new[] { 0 } }, new int[] { color }));
}
```

Outside of this, I also have an OnClickListener that updates the underline only when the state changes

```
private void ControlOnFocusChange(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs args)
{
    _hasFocus = args.HasFocus;
    SetUnderlineColor(args.HasFocus ? GetPlaceholderColor() : GetActivePlaceholderColor());
}
```

The problem is that when I tap into the EditText, it's hit or miss as to what I'm going to see for an underline color. 
I can pretty much guarantee that it'll be the default `android:colorAccent` the very first time. Then after that it switches between the "Hint Color" and the "Placeholder Color".

*note: if I change the `SetUnderlineColor` method to this (below), it no longer uses the "Hint Color" in the mix, but I still get the `android:colorAccent` color as the initial underline color, after that it behaves as expected.*

```
private void SetUnderlineColor(AColor color)
{
    var bg = EditText.Background;
    DrawableCompat.SetTint(bg,color);
    EditText.SetBackground(bg);
}
```

What do I need to do to set the INITIAL selected color of the EditText to my chosen `activeColor` / 'focused color' (purple)?

In this animation I am simply selecting and deselecting the EditText
[image]

Comment: What about using the `android:theme=="@style/MyEditText"` in your `EditText` tag, and the style can be this:`<style name="MyEditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"> 
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/defaultColor</item> 
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/activeColor </item>
</style>`.

Comment: Thanks @JoeLv but unfortunately there is no XML for me to do this with. This is going to be a re-usable control that gives the consumer access to the colors. The control is written completely in code.

Comment: You could extend application to set any defaults within the scope of the application

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really how Xamarin.Forms works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the solution for me was to go pure AppCompat

So I'm adding an `AppCompatEditText` to the `TextInputLayout`

```
protected EditText EditText => Control.EditText;

protected override TextInputLayout CreateNativeControl()
{
    var textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(Context);
    var editText = new AppCompatEditText(Context)
    {
        SupportBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(GetPlaceholderColor())
    };
    textInputLayout.AddView(editText);
    return textInputLayout;
}
```

Then from there I was able to set the underline consistently with this.

```
private void ControlOnFocusChange(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs args)
{
    _hasFocus = args.HasFocus;
    SetUnderlineColor(_hasFocus ?  GetActivePlaceholderColor(): GetPlaceholderColor());
} 

private void SetUnderlineColor(AColor color)
{
    var element = (ITintableBackgroundView)EditText;
    element.SupportBackgroundTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(color);
}
```

[full source code here.](https://github.com/XamFormsExtended/Xfx.Controls/blob/master/src/Xfx.Controls.Droid/Renderers/XfxEntryRendererDroid.cs)

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code in `XfxEntryRendererDroid` `ControlOnFocusChange` method like this :

```
private void ControlOnFocusChange(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs args)
{
    _hasFocus = args.HasFocus;
    if (_hasFocus)
    {
        ...   

        EditText.PostDelayed(() =>
            {
                //Add the following code
                SetUnderlineColor(GetActivePlaceholderColor());
                EditText.RequestFocus();
                manager.ShowSoftInput(EditText, 0);
            },
            0);//Change it to 0
    }
    ...
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO3ne.gif).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change the tint colour at runtime using this (May be in your text changed event):

```
ViewCompat.SetBackgroundTintList(_YourView , ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.ParseColor(Resources.GetString(Resource.Color.blueLine))));
```

Anyways Goodluck!

Comment: that's what I'm doing on the `ControlOnFocusChange` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the **backgroundTintList** or **supportBackgroundTintList** on the EditText to an instance of ColorStateList

```
ColorStateList colorStateList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
editText.setSupportBackgroundTintList(colorStateList)
```

**OR**

I think that if you want to change a bottom line color, then you can change using this below line

```
editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

And Application theame like this:-

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Please check this [Example](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialTextField)

Hope this [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584956/changing-the-color-of-edittexts-underline) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480398/edittext-underline-below-text-property) helps you.

Comment: EditText doesn't have `SupportBackgroundTintList` because it's not AppCompat. I've already tried using `SetBackgroundTintList`, but I'm getting the same behavior.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell  Please check example link. i thought it's helpful to you.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell check updated answer and example link. hope you'll get solution

Comment: Thank you for upvote my answer if it's going to help to someone.
Hey @ChaseFlorell mark as a right if this answer gave you a help.

Comment: I am not the upvote, unfortunately this does not solve the issue. The issue is that the very first time focus is given on the entry, the underline color is `colorAccent` instead of the color I've defined. Every subsequent focus sets the underline color appropriately. I don't know how to get it to be the correct color on the initial focus.

Comment: So I ended up making it work by switching out my `EditText` for an `AppCompatEditText`. Changing that out gave me access to `setSupportBackgroundTintList ` which ended up helping me get to where I needed to go. I posted the full answer and source code.

Comment: Ok great if your problem was solved then enjoy your day. @ChaseFlorell

Answer (score -1):

To change color you can use below code

```
 editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

And to set different color underline for EditText view on focus change

```
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_purple), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }else {
                editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if you look at the last two code blocks in my question, you'll see that is essentially what I'm doing.

Comment: You are trying to change background tint color. editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); will change existing drawable color only to the required color. Please give a try changing by this method. I tested and it is working perfectly fine