# android:Widget.Holo.Spinner shows black background

Tags: android, android-view, android-spinner, android-theme, android-styles

The default android spinner just shown a little arrow down. So, I tried to use Widget.Holo.Spinner which show an underline. Here is my style:

```
<style name="XRSpinner" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    ...
    ...
    ...
</style>
```

It shows ok on preview, but when I run it, the spinner shown a black background. I have also tried with `parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"`, but it still shows a black background.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

### UPDATED

Here is my application manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".XRWareStock"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My `minSdkVersion` is 19 and `targetSdkVersion` is 25.

Comment: Can you additionally specify the parent theme for the App/Activity you are using and also the API level on which you got this problem?

Comment: Hi pulp_fiction, I have updated my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for attribute, don't forget to Mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

> The default android spinner just shown a little arrow down

Holo themes are deprecated; don't worry, you don't have to reinvent the wheel to  create a custom spinner layout, there are several solutions like [BetterSpiner](https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner) which makes your life easier. It comes with several styles.

Comment: How can I make custom holo spinner with using style ? I want to incease height of spinner's underline . How can I done it?

Comment: @VishalVaishnav refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592451/change-size-of-edittext-bottom-border. This solution will also work for spinner

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish to have an underline and/or change the arrow?

**For the *underline***, you can change your style's parent to:

```
style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
```

**So for your style's name:**

```
<style name="XRSpinner" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined">
```

If you want to change the arrow's color:

**Java**

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOUR_COLOR), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

**XML**

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/YOUR_COLOR" />
```