# Android: Text Input Layout: How to change the height if the Edit Text Line

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles, android-textinputlayout

There is a way to change the color of the Edit Text line in TextInputLayout:

```
 <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/White</item>
 <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/red</item>
```

But is there some way to change the height of the Edit Text line?

Comment: The `EditText` bottom border you meant? If so, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592451/change-size-of-edittext-bottom-border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom drawable for that and apply it on edittext.

> edt_bg_selector.xml :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
item android:drawable="@drawable/edt_bg_selected" android:state_focused="true"/>
item android:drawable="@drawable/edt_bg_normal" android:state_focused="false"/>
/selector>
```

> edt_bg_normal.xml :

```
    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
</shape>
```

> edt_bg_selected.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="1px"
            android:color="#ff0000" />

        <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

> Layout file

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/edt_bg_selector" />
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot change the height of editext line, you can customise edittext line like this

```
android:backgroud=@null
```

and the under the edittext take a View and you can give color height width etc.

```
<View android:height="5dp"android:backgroud='#000000'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a predefined way to change `height`. However you can set a custom background on `EditText`, which background is a drawable, and you can set any property in that. Like color, height or padding. Check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34609916/6891563)

Answer (score 0):

@color/md_white_1000

```
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/md_white_1000</item>
</style>

<style name="MyHintText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/md_white_1000</item>
</style>

<style name="MyErrorText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/md_red_500</item>
</style>
```