# How can set the EditText line height?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

In my application I am using *EditText*. As we know that in new versions *EditText* does not have a border and it just displays a bottom line.

Now I want to set the height/thickness of the bottom line as 1dp.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23417544/1042124

Answer (score 3):

Just use the standard [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) with a [Filled Box](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#filled-box-default) style: `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox`.

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
    ...>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        .../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

It is the result:

[image]

The **default value** of the underline stroke in a filled box when it is not focused is **1dp**.

If you would like to customize the width you can use these attribute in the layout:

```
app:boxStrokeWidth="xxdp"
app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="xxdp"
```

or in a custom style:

```
<item name="boxStrokeWidth">xxdp</item>
<item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">xxdp</item>
```

**Note:** it requires the version `1.1.0`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Now I found in the 1.1.0 version thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/r..."
   android:thickness="3dp"
   android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#4799E8"/>
</shape>
```

add this in drawable resource file and in edit text change its background:

```
<EditText    
      android:background="@drawable/drawableResourceFileName"/>
```

Comment: This is not working, actually, it paints a complete rectangle frame and not the bottom line only